# Upload an image to firebase for a specific user

Tags: android, firebase-storage

How can I modify this code that can upload an image to firebase for a specific user, this creates a randomUUID. but I want to upload image under any specific UID:

```
StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("Profile/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(mainImageURI)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        setupProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        //progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You know that you can post text code on stackoverflow?

Comment: I have updated my code. please check it!

Answer (score 1):

You can create user profile in Cloud FireStore or RealTime DataBase for each new user that being created and save inside the name of the image, than use Firebase Storage to pull it out by image name.